# Требования к аппаратному и программному обеспечению для asp.net приложения

Tags: asp.net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должна быть минимальная конфигурация пк для работы asp.net приложения? Приложение работает с файлами Excel и XML, использует bootstrap фреймворк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формально - 1 GHz CPU, 512 MB RAM, 850 MB/2 GB HDD для x86/X64.

Это общие [минимальные системные требования к .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

На практике - будет работать на любом железе, на котором вы вообще сможете поставить Windows и .NET. Только на плохом железе все будет работать медленно.